# How to search into table B if the result of searching into table A is zero?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

I have three tables and I need to search in the first one, it there isn't any result, then search into second one and so on ..!

Here is my code:

```
// connecting to database
$stm1 = $this->dbh->prepare(" select * from table1 where col = :name; ");
$stm1->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm1->execute();
$which_table = "table1";

// the result of searching into table1 is zero, then search into table2
if (!$stm1->rowCount()) {
    $stm2 = $this->dbh->prepare(" select * from table2 where col = :name; ");
    $stm2->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm2->execute();
    $which_table = "table2";

    // the result of searching into table2 is zero, then search into table3
    if (!$stm2->rowCount()) {
        $stm3 = $this->dbh->prepare(" select * from table3 where col = :name; ");
        $stm3->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm3->execute();
        $which_table = "table3";

        // the result of searching into table3 is also zero
        if (!$stm3->rowCount()) {
            $which_table = 'none of them';
        }
    }
}
```

My code works as well, But it is slow, How can I optimize it and make it faster? As you see, there is three separated query and multiple if-statement .. How can I reduce them? Generally How can I improve that code? Can I do that using pure-sql?

Comment: First of all, do those three tables have different column structures? If not, they should be _one_ table to begin with. // You could combine the SELECT statements for all three tables via a UNION.

Comment: @CBroe If I combine them using `UNION ALL`, is there any grantee to I get the result of `table1` in first ? *(ordering perspective)*

Comment: You can order UNION results as you like, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html (And if you need the table name a result is from as well, you can select a text literal as a pseudo column as well, `SELECT 'table_a', … FROM table_a`, etc.)

Comment: Perhaps you should have 1 table, not 3?

Comment: @RickJames You are right, I will create one combined table containing all those tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you code is slow, then you probably just need indexes:

```
create index idx_table1_col on table1(col);
create index idx_table2_col on table2(col);
create index idx_table3_col on table3(col);
```

With indexes, you can also phrase the query as a single statement, assuming the columns in the tables are the same:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.col = :name
union all
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where t2.col = :name and
      not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.col = :name)
union all
select t3.*
from table3 t3
where t3.col = :name and
      not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.col = :name) and
      not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.col = :name);
```

This is a more complex query, but your code would only require a single query.  And, with indexes, it should be very fast.

Comment: Actually I created index of `col` column already .. But executing that code takes almost 0.4 sec  and for a lot of online-users on my website, my website hangs.

Comment: So, which of is your suggestion? Using PHP to handle it or a complex query?

Comment: @stack . . . That is really up to you.  In this case, I might think that the PHP code is easier to maintain.  However, I would question why your database has three tables with the same columns . . . there might be a simpler data structure overall.

Answer (score 1):

> My code works as well, But it is slow, How can I optimize it and make it faster?

Add index for the column `col`

By the way, you may add `limit 1` to your queries. It'll help you you have zillions of values in your tables to match